# How to get the specific text from the web page as text not enclosed in between any specific HTML tag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Can anyone help me with the following issue I came across. I could not find any solutions for it so far.

I would like to take the text:'standard_user' from the following html via XPath/css,but as there are no HTML tags I could not get the text in any way, I have tried with parent tag but getting all the username text but i want specifically only one.
Here is the html:

```
<div class="login_credentials_wrap">
<div class="login_credentials_wrap-inner">
<div id="login_credentials" class="login_credentials">
<h4>Accepted usernames are:</h4>
standard_user
<br>
locked_out_user
<br>
problem_user
<br>
performance_glitch_user
<br>
</div>
<div class="login_password">
<h4>Password for all users:</h4>
secret_sauce
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried with id=login_credentials but getting all the username and I want only specifically only one username.

Comment: You say you got all the usernames, but only wanted the first. The usernames are probably separated by either non-breaking spaces or some other form of whitespace or character - simply `.split()` the string by that character and get the first element `[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//div[@id="login_credentials"]/text()[1]
```

This XPath expression selects the first text node that is a direct child of the  element with the id "login_credentials". Since 'standard_user' is the first text node within that  element, this expression should retrieve it.

Comment: I have tried with your strategy but its throwing me the below error:

`InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@id="login_credentials"]/text()[1]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.`